# Issue using readNamespacedPodLog

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am trying to ascertain if there are log files for pods with sizes > 10Mb and reporting on them. When I do `readNamespacedPodLog` with a `limitBytes` of 10MB, I get size way less than that sometimes as much as half of that. I understand that the `readNamespacedPodLog` may return a little < or > the specified `limitBytes`, but can it be that much of a difference ?

I am using kubernetes-client jar 3.0.0.. I also tried switching to 4.0.0.

I am calling as below:

```java
apiInstance.readNamespacedPodLog(podName,namespace,null,
    false,10485760,"false",null,null,false)
```

For example, on a pod that I know has a log file > 11 Mb I consistently get about 6MB being returned.

If I switch to 5Mb, then it exactly returns 5Mb when the file has > 5Mb.

Is this how it should behave? Should I limit to 5 and do a continuous couple of 5 Mb reads to ascertain if the file has 10 Mb?

Comment: You are omitting to set the optional parameter `previous`. The default values of `previous` is set to false, this means that only the logs of the current execution of the pod will be returned. Are you sure that all the 11 Mb of logs hosted in the pod are about the current execution? Can you try to set the parameter `previous` to true and see what happens?

Comment: Isnt the previous parameter to get the previously terminated container logs ?  when I exec into the kubelet, Im able to see that the pod has 11mb. Im pretty sure thats the current execution size..

Comment: Could you please check whether you see more logs either with the command `kubectl logs my-pod` or with the endpoint ‘/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/pods/<pod>/log’?
If not, this means that the problem comes neither from the java API, nor from gke, but most likely from the configuration of the logrotation tool (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)

If you are able to see more logs, in which folder are you checking or which command are you using?

Comment: @VKR, thanks a lot, I think the issue for a specific pod. I was getting all the other pod log sizes correctly. when I did kubectl logs on that specific pod, kubectl also reported only the reduced size, I manually restarted the pod and now Im ok. Sorry for the delayed reply, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with one specific pod. Issue has gone after pod restart.
For all other pods log sizes are correct.